# EFCore 2.0 default all date fields to use datetime2

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In EF6 i could use the following code so that all my dates use datetime2(0) as the column type

```
modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>()
    .Configure(c => c
    .HasColumnType("datetime2")
    .HasPrecision(0));
```

How can i do this in EFCore??

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277154/entity-framework-core-setting-the-decimal-precision-and-scale-to-all-decimal-p/43282620#43282620

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Core - setting the decimal precision and scale to all decimal properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277154/entity-framework-core-setting-the-decimal-precision-and-scale-to-all-decimal-p)

Comment: Not having the correct column type can lead to this error: `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`. That's how I found this question.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install the Nuget Package: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer. After install, you can use HasColumnType("datetime") in your property.
:)

Comment: Thanks, this saved my day. If you're using attributes instead, it's `[Column(TypeName = "datetime")]`

Comment: This does not default for all columns of the same time like specified in the OP.  You have to configure it for each column