# Does entity framewrk core IEntityTypeConfiguration class hava HasPrecision() function?

Tags: entity-framework-core

In the EF6 ,I can mapping field like:

```
Property(_ => _.Total_Excursion).HasColumnName("TOTAL_EXCURSION").HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                    .HasPrecision(12, 2);
```

now i use ef core ,I can't use  HasPrecision() funciton.
Are there any other alternative method？

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework Core - setting the decimal precision and scale to all decimal properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277154/entity-framework-core-setting-the-decimal-precision-and-scale-to-all-decimal-p)

Comment: As the duplicate's answer shows, in EF Core 3 you can use `SetColumnType`. In EF Core 5, `SetPrecision`. For earlier versions - don't use them if you can, go straight to EF Core 3.1. It's a .NET Standard 2.0 package which means you can use it in .NET Core 2.1 as well. EF Core 1.x was too quirky to use, and EF Core 2.x still had some unpleasant features like client-side evaluation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer,
using EF3:

```
Property(_ => _.Total_Excursion)
            .HasColumnName("TOTAL_EXCURSION")
            .HasColumnType("decimal(12, 2)");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it.

If you are using EF3

```
Property(_ => _.Total_Excursion)
            .HasColumnName("TOTAL_EXCURSION")
            .SetColumnType("decimal(12, 2)");
```

If you are on EF5

```
 Property(_ => _.Total_Excursion)
                .HasColumnName("TOTAL_EXCURSION")
                .property.SetPrecision(12);
                .property.SetScale(2);
```

Comment: In EF core 3 EntityTypeBuilder, I got a error  cs1912 :PropertyBuilder<decimal?> does not contain a definition of  SetColumnType