# ASP.NET Core prevent decimal rounding by default

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a column in a database table with a datatype of `decimal(7, 3)`. When I enter this number (`0.729`) in input box, it will be updated to `0.730`. I want to prevent this rounding. I have tried to set this data annotation to the field in the view model class, but it didn't work. I use `ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync` to execute the stored procedure but I can't find any way to solve that issue.

The action in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateElements(updateProductElementsViewModel model)
{
    var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
    {
        await _appDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync($"exec SPApp_ProductElementsUpdate {userId},{model.id},{model.productName},{model.Density},{model.Ron}");
    }

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
}
```

The stored procedure parameter:

```
@Density decimal(7,3)
```

The auto property on the `updateProductElementsViewModel` class:

```
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(7,3)")]
public decimal Density { get; set; }
```

The `OnModelCreating` method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<updateProductElementsViewModel>()
                .Property(x => x.Density)
                .HasColumnType("decimal(7,3)");

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Do you use Attribute- and OnModelCreating- Mapping in parallel? Or did. you show, what you‘ve tried?

Comment: @Nikolaus I found  this after use the profiling in sql server Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync will generate decimal(18,2) by default I think this is cause of the main issue !

Comment: I enabled logged to EF core and found this ( 

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (107ms) [Parameters=[@p3='0.729' (Precision = 18) (Scale = 2) ` )  by default  the decimal precision = 18 and Scale =2  I have no idea how to ride this issue so I need increases the  Scale part.

Comment: Maybe this can help: [decimal in EFCore ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277154/entity-framework-core-setting-the-decimal-precision-and-scale-to-all-decimal-p/43282620)