# EF Core: set precision for all decimal properties of certain entity class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a class which has several float properties

```cs
class BodyParameters
{
    public float Weight { get; set; }
    public float Height { get; set; }
    public float ThighLength { get; set; }
}
```

How do I set the same precision and scale to all properties that is a float in my "BodyParameters" entity class?

My current solution is set them one by one in ModelBuilder, which may take lots of manual work since the entity class can have as many as of 40 properties:

```cs
builder.Entity<BodyParameters>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(entity => entity.Height)
        .HasPrecision(5, 2);
    entity.Property(entity => entity.Weight)
        .HasPrecision(5, 2);
    entity.Property(entity => entity.ThighLength)
        .HasPrecision(5, 2);
});
```

I have found similar questions: [Entity Framework Core - setting the decimal precision and scale to all decimal properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277154/entity-framework-core-setting-the-decimal-precision-and-scale-to-all-decimal-p).

But I only need to set precisions to float properties in my **entity class**, not my **DbContext**.

**Edit:**
I just found that I can't use float with HasPrecision (at least for MS SqlServer), so all float properties should be changed to decimal.

Comment: Unfortunately, Entity Framework Core does not provide a built-in attribute or mechanism to specify precision directly on entity properties.Precision is typically configured at the database level

Comment: you can use reflection and modelbuilder to automate the process of setting precision for all float properties in your entity class.

Comment: Since EF7 there are [Model building conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#model-building-conventions). See [Example: Default length for all string properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#example-default-length-for-all-string-properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an extension method like the one below. Basically, it gets all the properties that have the specified type and calls `HasPrecision` on them :

```
  public static ModelBuilder SetAllPrecision<TEntity>(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, Type targetPropertyType, int precision, int scale)
  {
      var entityType = typeof(TEntity);

      var targetProperties = entityType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(r => r.PropertyType == targetPropertyType);
      foreach (var property in targetProperties)
      {
          var propertyType = property.PropertyType;
          modelBuilder.Entity(entityType).Property(property.Name).HasPrecision(precision, scale);

      }

      return modelBuilder;
  }
```

You can use it like this :

```
builder.SetAllPrecision<BodyParameters>(typeof(float),5,2);
```

Comment: There might be a typo, it should be
`modelBuilder.Entity(entityType).Property(property.Name)` instead of `propertyType.Name` ?